# Pass value to Bootstrap modal with GWT/GwtQuery

Tags: java, gwt, twitter-bootstrap, gwtquery

How to pass a value with a modal using GWT/GwtQuery

```
<div  class="modal-body">
<input id="myId" data-field="myId" type="text" value="" style="display: none;"> 
</div>
```

This is what I have tried but did not work:

```
DOM.setEventListener(editTD, new EventListener(){
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(
       com.google.gwt.user.client.Event event) {
       if (event.getTypeInt() != com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.ONCLICK) {
                return;
       }
       $(".modal-body #myId").val(String.valueOf(info.getId())); 
}});
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more your question? what is editTD?, what is info? what do you mean with bootstrap modal?.

Comment: editTD is a com.google.gwt.user.client.Element

Comment: Does `$(".modal-body #myId")` return elements? try: `Window.alert($(".modal-body #myId").size())`